# Compare script output from remote server with local result

Tags: ssh, sql, shell-scripting

I want to run this SQL on the local and remote host:

```
select concat_ws('.', table_schema, table_name, column_name) as column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
order by table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position;
```

The above SQL gets called via `psql -c "..."`

The `psql` command on the remote host gets called via `ssh remote-host psql ...`

Then I want to compare the remote and local result with `vimdiff`.

Trying to do this with the shell drives me crazy since the quoting is not trivial.

Is there a tool which can help here?

My dream:

```
compare-with-remote foo@remote-host psql -c "SELECT ..."
```

The tool should be universal (not just for psql).

Yes, I know this **could** be done with the shell in one big ugly command line, but I search a clean, simple and readable solution where I don't need to escape quote chars.

I know how to do this interactively with the bash shell in several steps. I have done comparisons like this several time during the last years. Sometimes I call psql sometimes other commands.

Background: The above SQL outputs the tables and the columns in ordinal_position. Related. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120715/compare-order-of-columns-between-two-databases

Comment: If it's always the same SQL, I'd combine shell scripts: put `query.sql` on both hosts, then capture output in two (temporary) files which you can diff. No difficult quoting needed, and no extra tools.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, that's the solution I use since years. But there could be an easier way.

Comment: Ah. You didn't write that. Your question reads as if you would pass the SQL *command* at the prompt, and hence need "difficult quoting" :)

Comment: @Izzy I updated the question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: It still looks like you're running something like `ssh <remote> psql -c "SELECT …"` – while I recommended putting the entire SQL into a file and rather run something like `ssh <remote> "psql < script.sql"` – which would rid you of all that "quote escaping trouble".

Comment: @Izzy The tool should be universal (not just for psql).

Comment: I don't know of any tool not accepting an SQL file as input. But OK, I gave my hint – you got it :) Now good luck for answers.